# How to visit a bidimensional array and use if statement inside it - PHP

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, foreach

I have an **array** which is the result of a MySQLi query.

The array code is:

```
while ($row_Active = mysqli_fetch_assoc($SeqActive)) {
    $Seq[] = $row_Active;
}
```

If I echo out the array it has the correct content so I know trhat works.

**Goal:**

I need to loop through the array (using foreach, I think) so **if the content of an array element contains "1" then `echo 1` else `echo 2`.**

How can I read the content of each element to make this work?

```
$SeqID = array();
foreach($Seq as $key => $value) {
    if($value == 1){
    echo "1";
    } else {
    echo "2";
    }
}
```

The able is only my way of describing what I need.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

---

**Edit:**

I discovered that SQL query returned a bidimensional array as below:

the results of the query:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Status] => A [SeqID1] => 1 [SeqID2] => 1 [SeqID3] => [SeqID4] => [SeqID5] => [SeqID6] => [SeqID7] => [SeqID8] => [SeqID9] => [SeqID10] => [SeqID11] => [SeqID12] => [SeqID13] => [SeqID14] => [SeqID15] => [SeqID16] => [SeqID17] => [SeqID18] => [SeqID19] => [SeqID20] => [SeqID21] => [SeqID22] => [SeqID23] => [SeqID24] => [SeqID25] => [SeqID26] => [SeqID27] => [SeqID28] => [SeqID29] => [SeqID30] => [SeqID31] => [SeqID32] => [SeqID33] => [SeqID34] => [SeqID35] => [SeqID36] => [SeqID37] => [SeqID38] => [SeqID39] => [SeqID40] => [SeqID41] => [SeqID42] => [SeqID43] => [SeqID44] => [SeqID45] => [SeqID46] => [SeqID47] => ) )
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks for all the replies.

I have taken all comments onbaord and this is very close to working.

The whole code produces a table of questions, each question displays a button, if the question has already been answered the question display a green image and if the question as not been answered it displays a red button.

The code provided works great but when I include it in my working script the questions are not displayed.

Any ideas as to why the questions are not displaying.

I did not want to put all the code in to the post from the start because I thought it may cloud the issue.

The whole code:

```
<? do { ?>  
    <? $_SESSION['TableID'] = $row_SeqList['TableID'];?>
    <tr>
       <td width="71%" class="tablelist"><?php print $row_SeqHead['SeqHeader']; ?></td>
       <td width="7%" class="tablelist"><?php print $row_SeqHead['TableID']; ?></td>
       <td width="16%" class="openbutton">
        <?php foreach($Seq as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $val) { 
                if ($val == 1){ ?>
                <img src="images/completebutton.png" width="72" height="29">            
                <? } else { ?>
                <a href="table01.php?TableID=<?php echo $row_SeqHead['TableID']; ?>" target="_self"><img src="images/openbutton.png" width="72" height="29"></a>

        <?php }
        }

    }?>
<?php } while ($row_SeqHead = mysqli_fetch_assoc($SeqHead)); ?>
```

Comment: Could you show the data you are getting from the query.

Comment: Add one more foreach to loop rows - `foreach($Seq as $row) { foreach($row as $key => $value) {`

Answer (score 1):

You **should use two** `foreach` **loops** to get the elements values. Here is your example

```
$SeqID = array();
while ($row_Active = mysqli_fetch_assoc($SeqActive)) {
    $Seq[] = $row_Active;
}

$one = 0;
$two = 0;
foreach($Seq as $key => $data) {
    foreach($data as $key_2 => $value ) {
        if($value == 1){
            $one++;
        } else {
            $two++;
        }
    }
}
echo "Total records with one : ".$one."<br>";
echo "Total records with two : ".$two;
```

Comment: @nerdlyist, I have edited the question and placed the array content in the post

Comment: Hi @Rafael Shkembi, the $row_Active is populated, see post edit with array content. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: $SeqID is different from $Seq so nothing is re-assigned

Comment: I am right but you are not. In the OP's code there was not this bug, so please rewrite the first part of the answer

Comment: @Rafael Shkembi, I have updated the post with additional code to show exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: The questions are those values in your td tags?

Comment: @Rafael Shkembi, Hi yes the questions are in the td tag.

Comment: Make the while on the questions

Comment: @Rafael Shkembi, many thanks for all your help and time. I will have to try and do this a different way because its jyst not working. If I put "while" on the question it displays all the questions on one row from left to right. But again, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you are going to need another foreach loop which is called nested foreach loops

here is a code i wrote and tested and working fine

```
$one = $two = 0; // empty variables 
foreach($Seq as $key => $value) {

        foreach ($value as $val) {              
        if ($val == 1) {
            $one++;
        }else {
            $two++;
        }
    }
}
echo "total number of one's ". $one ."<br>";
echo "total number of two's ". $two ."<br>";
```